# Prevent Material UI Typography Text from going outside its parent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Typography element within a `div` as shown below:

```
        <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            minHeight: 180,
            minWidth: 200
        }}>
            <Typography
                className={classes.multiLineEllipsis}
                textAlign={'center'}
            >
                {veryLongText}
            </Typography>

           {...otherElements}
        </div>
```

It turns out that if the text within the Typography element is too long it starts going outside the parent `div` element. I don't want that behavior, I want it to wrap the text and stay within its parent.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `noWrap` attribute for the Typography tag

```js
<div style={{
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  minHeight: 180,
  minWidth: 200
}}>
  <Typography
      className={classes.multiLineEllipsis}
      textAlign={'center'}
      no
  >
      {veryLongText}
  </Typography>

 {...otherElements}
</div>
```

Read more about it [here](https://mui.com/api/typography/#:%7E:text=a%20bottom%20margin.-,noWrap,-bool).

Answer (score 0):

on [typography api](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/) you can find a noWrap prob so you can add it like below

```
<Typography sx={{ fontSize: 10 }} noWrap={true}>
          your text
        </Typography>
```